# why thread isnt stopping at count 3?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to do a little exercise on threads and I just started learning thread and other stuff.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ThreadDemo extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("counting" + count);
        }
        if (count == 3) {
            try {
                Thread t = new Thread();
                t.wait(5000);
                System.out.println("thread waiting");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThreadDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadDemo obj = new ThreadDemo();
        obj.start();
    }
}
```

Output of the given

```
counting1
counting2
counting3
counting4
counting5
counting6
```

Comment: `count == 3` is always false. it will be 6 after you increment it 6 times. I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to understand it better.

Comment: `t.wait(5000)` doesn't do what you think it does.  When your code executes `t.wait(5000)` it is calling the `Object` class `wait()` method.  You should read the [Guarded Blocks Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) before you go messing with `Object.wait()`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When the test `if (count == 3)` is done the value of `count` is `6`.

And your code test it only once.

You need to move the code that is out of the for loop inside it.

You need also to hold a lock on `t` before call `wait`. This is done with a synchronized block.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("counting" + count);

        // Moved block
        if (count == 3) {
            try {
                Thread t = new Thread();
                synchronized (t) {  
                    t.wait(5000);
                }
                System.out.println("thread waiting");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThreadDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        // End of moved block
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
counting1
counting2
counting3
thread waiting     // Note: this will be printed after 5 seconds
counting4
counting5
counting6
```

A similar result, but not identical can be obtained using Thread.sleep, replacing this code

```
Thread t = new Thread();
synchronized (t) {  
   t.wait(5000);
}
```

With the following:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

A difference between Thread.sleep and Object.wait is that is possible to awake a thread waiting acquiring his lock and calling [notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) (or [notifyAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll())).

Instead is not possible to awake a thread sleeping with Thread.sleep.

Comment: Worked fine but what if i want to join after count 3 ,so what i need to do in order to resume from 3.

Comment: BTW You can't `wait` on an object you are not holding a lock on.

Comment: @user156538 you only have one thread running. What are you joining?

Comment: @user156538 exactly what you expect to do?

Comment: After interval of time it should start that thread automatically.this i wanted to implement.

Comment: And it throws exception illegal monitor state exception

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO throws exception

Comment: @user156538 yes because as explained by Peter you need to acquire a lock over the object on wich you invoke the wait. You can do adding a synchronized block surrounding the wait call

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO and how do i implement that?